# How to use assign to modify part of a vector in R?

Tags: r, assign

The R help for assign says: "assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc."  Lower down, in the examples, we are shown:

```
a <- 1:4
assign("a[1]", 2)
a[1] == 2          # FALSE
get("a[1]") == 2   # TRUE
```

I would like to know how to solve the problem that this example points out - given a character string representing part of a vector or data frame, how can I assign into that location?  I can fetch the values:

```
x <- "a[1]"
eval(parse(text=x))  # 1
```

and of course I can assign into part of a vector

```
a[1:2] <- c(0,0)
```

so how do I put these together, if I am starting with the character string?

---

Thank you LauriK, but my difficulty is that the string is "a[1:2]", so even the get will fail.  I'll explain the reasoning that got me to ask this question.

I have two data frames, one like this:

```
> df
  Fiscal Year  Num Deferrals  1 Yr Prob
1        2015             0        100%
2        2016             0        100%
3        2017            65         98%
2 Year Total             65         n/a
2 Year Average           32         n/a
```

and another like this:

```
> sv
nDeferrals   nSmallDeferrals   oneYrProb
          0                 0      1.0000
          0                 0      1.0000
         65                63       .9797
```

I want to save descriptions of parts of these two things, and during future runs, as long as the first one doesn't change, I will replace it with the value of the second. So I have two character strings:

```
"df$'1 Yr Prob'[1:3]"
"sv$oneYrProb"
```

As long as "df$'1 Yr Prob[1:3]" doesn't change, I will overwrite it with whatever the value of "sv$oneYrProb" is at the future run time.  I'm saving the names of the two variables, and the value of the first one at the time it gets frozen:

```
freeze <- function(R_name, saved_name) {
    frozen <- new.env()
    R_value <- eval(parse(text=R_name))
    with(frozen, assign(R_name, list(R_name, R_value, saved_name)))
    save(frozen, file="frozen.RData")
}
```

The result is that the "frozen" environment contains variables that look like this:

```
> frozen$"df$'1 Yr Prob'[1:3]"
[[1]]
[1] "df$\"1 Yr Prob\"[1:3]"

[[2]]
[1] "100% "100%" "98%"

[[3]]
[1] "sv$oneYrProb"
```

So I have character strings representing the two objects in the test, and the value of the first one at the time it was frozen.
I can get the values of the objects - using "eval(parse" -, but I don't know how to store back into the first one.  I have:

```
processFreezeList <- function() {
    load("frozen.RData", envir=.GlobalEnv)
    variables <- ls(frozen)
    for (v in variables) {
        temp <- get(v, frozen)
        R_name <- temp[[1]]
        R_value <- temp[[2]]
        saved_name <- temp[[3]]
        if (all(eval(parse(text=R_name)) == R_value))
            assign(R_name, eval(parse(text=saved_name)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
    }
}
```

Instead of writing over the first object, the assign creates a new variable:

```
"df$/"1 Yr Prob/"[1:3]"
```

With that string I can fetch the values it represents, but I don't know how to write back over them.  To solve the original problem I'm turning to substitute but it does seem like it should be doable with strings.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? You probably don't. If you're using `eval()` or `assign()`, there's almost always a "better", more "R-like," way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to the problem that motivated my question, and I think it can be generalized.  It looks like this:

```
a <- c(1,1,1)
b <- c(2,2,2)
x <- "a[1]"
y <- "b[1]"
eval(parse(text=paste(x,"<-",y)
a
[1] 2 1 1
```

In other words, bring the assignment itself into the string and eval that.

Comment: @RichardScriven I want to thank LauriK and RichardScriven for helping me puzzle through this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to change parts of vectors while only knowing the vector name as a string variable. Try something like this:

```
> (a <- letters[1:5])
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> x <- "a"
> var.x <- get(x)
> var.x[1:2] <- c(0,0)
> assign(x, var.x)
> a
[1] "0" "0" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: @RichardScriven please explain. I added the first line to my answer and it works as an answer to the original question. Now that I've seen the original question heavily edited, I'll take a look at it in a few hours and see if I can come up with a better answer.

Comment: Well you original answer triggered an error in `get(x)` because `a` was not defined.   And hence triggered error in every call.

Comment: @LauriK I am still at sea here.  My string is not like "a". It is one of many variations on "a[1]"   and get("a[1]") does not work.